# Notifications job date format

Tags: rundeck

I need a hint: how to change date format on jobs notification?
I can't figure it out. As far as I understand, is related to messages.properties file, which I 
can't find.
I created i18n directory with messages.properties file, but I'm not sure what is the format of messages file content. (found on [albundy83 comment](https://github.com/rundeck/rundeck/issues/1682#issuecomment-185070518))

```
Date dateS = Date.parse( "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS", execution.dateStarted.toString() )
String dateStartedIso8601 = dateS.format( "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ" )

Date dateE = Date.parse( "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS", execution.dateEnded.toString() )
String dateEndedIso8601 = dateE.format( "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ" )
```

I have installed Rundeck 3.2.2 using RPM on CentOS 8.

Regards,
Adi

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To use that custom format you need to create a groovy plugin, follow [this](https://docs.rundeck.com/docs/developer/05-notification-plugins.html#groovy-plugin-type). Basically you need to create a .groovy file and put it on `$RDECK_BASE/libext` (as any plugin).

I did an basic example modifying [this](https://github.com/rundeck/rundeck/blob/master/examples/example-groovy-notification-plugins/MinimalNotificationPlugin.groovy) plugin and [this](https://github.com/rundeck/rundeck/issues/1682#issuecomment-185070518). Take a look:

```java
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat 
import java.util.Date
import com.dtolabs.rundeck.plugins.notification.NotificationPlugin;

rundeckPlugin(NotificationPlugin){
    onstart { 
        println("job start: data ${execution}")
        true
    }

    onfailure {
        println("failure: data ${execution}")
        true
    }

    onsuccess {
        Date dateS = Date.parse( "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS", execution.dateStarted.toString() )
        String customdate = dateS.format( "dd-MM-YYYY" )

        println("success: data ${customdate}")
        true
    }
}
```

Output (success job execution):

```bash
success: data 18-02-2020
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply.

I forgot to mention something important.
I'm using a HTML template for notifications and I configured custom properties in rundeck-config file, as below:
`rundeck.mail.template.subject
rundeck.mail.template.file`

html page section
`Date started:**${execution.dateStarted}**`

If I understand the situation correctly, in the groovy file (plugin) I have to define the entire output of the notification.
If I'm wrong (hope so), how can be used that new date format, defined in groovy file, in the html notification template page?

Comment: The default notification plugins (like a plugin that are you using) the date format is unmodifiable (you can suggest it here: https://github.com/rundeck/rundeck/issues). You can create a groovy or java custom plugin that parse the  ${execution.dateStarted} and print the date in your format (like the example in my answer). You have more info about this here: https://docs.rundeck.com/docs/developer/05-notification-plugins.html. Also, you have a good example: https://github.com/rundeck/rundeck/blob/master/examples/example-groovy-notification-plugins/MailNotificationPlugin.groovy